# Element in centraliser of a group IFF conjugacy class of g in G is the collection of g.

Tags: group-theory

> Lemma: $g \in Z\left ( G \right )$ If and ony If $g^{G}=\left \{ g \right \}
> $

$\par$

> Let G be a group and $h \in G$
>
> The conjugacy class of $h \in G$ is
>   $h^{G}=Cl_{G}\left ( h \right )=\left \{ g^{-1}hg|g \in G \right \}$

$\par$

> The centraliser of G:
>   $Z\left ( G \right )=\left \{ g \in G|gx=xg ,\forall x \in G \right \}$

$g \in Z\left ( G \right )$ so $gx=xg \forall x \in G$

$gx=xg \Rightarrow \left (g^{-1}g  \right )x=g^{-1}xg\Rightarrow \left ( e \right )x=g^{-1}xg\Rightarrow x=g^{-1}xg$

Now, clearly, the conjugacy class of g in G is

$g^{G}=Cl_{G}\left ( g \right )=\left \{ g^{-1}gg|g \in G \right \}=\left \{ g \right \}.$

I need to show how $x=g^{-1}xg$ leads to $g^{G}=Cl_{G}\left ( g \right )= \left \{ g \right \}.$

Could I get some hint? I've a feeling my notation is the culprit here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion is that you are not using different variables, when defining the conjugacy class of $g$ in $G$. It should be $g^G=\{h^{-1}gh:h\in G\}$. That is, $g$ is fixed and $h$ ranges throughout all elements in $G$. As you defined in the question, $g^G=\{g\}$ in every case, but this is not true in general.

Now, to prove the lemma, you have:

$$g\in G \Leftrightarrow gh=hg\text{ for all $h\in G$} \Leftrightarrow h^{-1}gh=g\text{ for all $h\in G$} \Leftrightarrow g^G=\{h^{-1}gh:h\in G\}=\{g\}$$

[If necessary, you can show the last part by double contenence]